# Firefox is encoding client-side template curly braces

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, jquery-templates

I got an aspx code that looks like this

```
<img src="${image_item_path}" />
```

On Chrome/IE don't have problem, but Firefox render it like this

```
<img src="%7Bimage_item_path%7D" />
```

Note: I'm using the jQuery Template engine

Comment: Shouldn't that be replaced by an URL on the server-side? I don't think that value is supposed to land on the browser...

Comment: Yes, you are right, it should be replaced by an URL on the server side but I got that.

Comment: When you say "I don't have any problem", what does that mean? Is this a client-side template? If that's a server-side variable, I can't see how that would work right at all if the browser sees that `src`.

Comment: Is a client-side template, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/

Comment: I think there are other parts of this we'd need to know. How are you generating that img tag? Is it straight HTML, or are you using a .NET image control?  Are you seeing this URL encoded value when you View Source, or through something like Firebug?  Also, what version of Firefox are you seeing this in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry folks, it's a well-known issue with the template engine I'm using. I'm wrapping the img element into a div rather than a script block.

This is the answer I was looking for:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/issues/147

Thank you all